# ASP.NET MVC & IE9 Input Type number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Im currently using input type number, but as ie9 does not support this type, does anyone have any good alternatives(and example)? im using ASP.NET MVC4 if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery UI Spinner Widget](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/) is an alternative. You could combine it with Modernizr to only use the jQuery UI Spinner Widget with browsers that natively doesn't support number as input type

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.number) {
            $("input[type=number]").spinner();
        };
    });
</script>
```

Have a look at this [jsFiddle demonstration using Modernizr](http://jsfiddle.net/vf4aR/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes basically give your input field a class as jqNos

And use this script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(".jqNos").each(function () {
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        var code = $.browser.mozilla ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        if (((code >= 48) && (code <= 57)) || code == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

This script will allow only numbers in your text box.